# Python Jira: Get version release date by version name

Tags: python-3.x, jira, jira-plugin, python-jira

I've below code to read fix version name:

```
from jira import JIRA

jira_options = {'server': 'URL'}
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('username', 'pwd'), options = {'server': 'username'})
fix_version = getparsedstring(issue.fields.fixVersions) #since fix Versions is not readable version name, using getparsedstring custom function to get readable string
```

Objective is  to get release date of the version from issue, as I will be reading all issues of project through iterations.

As per answer given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669848/get-release-date-for-project-version-with-jira-python), below would retrieve release date:

```
i = jira.version(v.id, expand="ReleaseDate")
i.releaseDate
```

How do I get release date using issue details through JIRA library?

Note: I do not want to read it through REST API

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Getting Release Date information directly from Issue

```
issue = jira.issue('PRJ-1234')

# iterate through all fixVersions of the current issue
for fixVersion in issue.fields.fixVersions:
    # print fixVersion Name and respective Release Date
    print(f'{fixVersion.name} has the release date: {fixVersion.releaseDate}')
```

---

### Getting Release Date information from mapping table in a dictionary

Another option is to create a release map:

```
# create dictionary with release name as key and release date as value
def createReleaseVersionMap(jira, project):
    versions = jira.project_versions(project)

    # Make a map from version name -> version release date
    for version in versions:
        try:
            prjVersionList[version.name] = version.releaseDate

        # if no release date is set for this version,
        # do something else, e.g., use the name as value instead of the date
        except AttributeError:
            prjVersionList[version.name] = version.name

    return prjVersionList
```

And then just use the dictionary in your code to retrieve the respective release dates:

```
my_release_map = createReleaseVersionMap(jira, 'PRJ')
release_date_I_need = my_release_map['Release Name']
```